# Converting Hex 0x5A into string "0x5A" not into "Z" in C

Tags: c

I'm getting a bunch of hex characters from a peripheral which I then want to print into a txt file as a string. I've found loads of examples of people converting hex into ascii string such as 0x5A in "Z" but can't find any examples of turning 0x5A into "0x5A". Can someone point me in the right direction?

Cheers!

Comment: If you are getting hex characters as input, then you just need to print them as is.

Comment: As in just use sprintf(string,"%x",hex) ?

Comment: If your input is hex characters (e.g. '5' followed by 'A') then just print them. If your input is numbers then it is not hex, and your question is misleading. It seems like you actually want to know how to format a number as hex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print a *value* in hex just use the `%x` format specifier with `printf`, e.g.

```
uint8_t n = 0x5a;

printf("%x\n", n);     // 5a
printf("%#x\n", n);    // 0x5a
```

(Note that `%#x` gives you an `0x` prefix on your hex value.)

Comment: comment to OP: Use X if you want 0x5A and x if you want it 0x5a

Comment: Ok great, think that should do the trick. Feel a bit silly for not thinking of that in the first place. Is there a way to get rid of the 0x or will I need to just do that manually?

Comment: Use `%x` for `5a` or `%#x` for `0x5a`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    char Z = 'Z';
    char outbuff[5];
    sprintf(outbuff, "0x%02X", (unsigned)Z);
    printf("%s\n", outbuff);
    return(0);
}
```